# If my computer boots up in safe mode, does that mean my SSD is still alive?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, safe-mode

So I have a desktop PC at home. Today, after several weeks of not using it, I turned it on and it didn't boot up. It basically just loads a blank, black screen. This PC is fairly new and hasn't been used much and has hardly anything installed on it. It's basically only got Chrome, Office, Visual Studio and SQL Server on it.

I'm trying to figure out whether its the hardware. I don't think it's RAM or CPU related because I feel like the system would just be random and glitchy or it wouldn't work at all. I'm thinking it might be my SSD but I've been able to boot it up into Safe Mode and in Safe Mode I can see all my files. I can even see new event logs being generated and I've even saved files. Does that mean that it is likely my SSD drive is fine? Would a failing SSD drive allow anything to be read or written to?

Is there some sort of "hardware test" program that I can run and check each component and make sure it's all working fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SSD is still alive, yes. It looks to me that the problem might be with Windows.

You could try to open CMD as administrator and run something like `chkdsk C: /f` (before Win10) or `chkdsk C: /scan` (Win10)
While benefits of running chkdsk on an SSD are somewhat limited, it may still find something.

You can also try `sfc /scannow` (again in CMD ran as administrator).

Looking at the event log may also be useful. Press windows button and type 'Event Viewer', and run this application. Then in the 'Summary of Administrative Events' try to look for critical and errors around the time your system booted into the black screen.

Another thing to do could be reinstalling graphics drivers.

Basically, there is a whole set of possible problems that can lead to booting into a black screen. I just named a couple of things I would try.

Comment: looks like it's not my SSD. Think it must be a windows thing, turned out that it did something to my multiple monitor setup. Cause once it loads, if I press Win - P. I'm able to get the login screen to show up. Now my problem seems to be it doesn't recognise the monitor that's plugged into the HDMI port (only the DVI one works) which is a bit weird

Comment: I actually have a similar set up (HDMI and DVI monitors), with DVI being "primary" and showing the login screen. Which is primary for you? Have you tried to reinstall graphics drivers?

Comment: yeah I ended up reinstalling the graphics drivers and it worked. Not sure what happened, I think a Windows update did something but it's all working now!

Comment: GPU drivers are quite complex software and sometimes things like these just do happen. Glad your problem is solved!